# Use data in multiple view controllers under a tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `songs = [Song]()` array of song objects being generated in the first view controller of my tab bar.

How can i use this array in the other view controllers of the UITabBarController?

I need to show this in my initial view controller, a table containing all songs, but also need to use this data in a second view controller, a table containing only favourite songs.

Comment: How are you creating this array? From coreData?

Comment: My first view controller creates it by parsing an XML file for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution would be to create another class for managing the songs data. Basically, you want to add a model for your view controller to look at. In this new class, you may decide you want to use a singleton to provide the exact same data to every object viewing the data. This is similar to what core data does, and is something I think you should consider using (core data works with xml). But, by having a class other than your view controller manage your data, any view controller (or any other object) that needs access to the data need only ask the data class for it.

Comment: So, you're saying best practice here is to define another "Songs" class and do the parsing there?

Comment: Well, not quite. I would probably make a song class, which contained all the required info for any one particular song. Then, I would want some way of managing all the song objects (that's where core data is really helpful). If you don't use core data, I would create some kind of class to do all that management for me. This class should hand off specific info to the Song class (i.e. pieces of the xml) to allow the song class to create objects. Then this class should keep track of all those objects, passing them around as needed.